# Split data into batches in Tensorflow for classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

I am training the data using below code. But here I need to split the data into batches (as giving in MNIST tensorflow example:  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)).

When I looked for next_batch method, it was not available in any library. I am a newbie to Tensor flow. Just wondering whether I can split the data into batches while training.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
for i in range(training_epochs):  
  sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_: inputY}) # Take a gradient descent step using our inputs and labels

# That's all! The rest of the cell just outputs debug messages. 
# Display logs per epoch step
  if (i) % display_step == 0:
    cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_:inputY})
    print "Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc) #, \"W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b)

print "Optimization Finished!"
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: inputX, y_: inputY})
print "Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

`next_batch` isn't a general-purpose library method. It is a method specific to the MNIST data set that reads the next minibatch of inputs to feed te Tensorflow.

You can see its implementation here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160

You would need to implement something similar for your dataset.
This code isn't specific to Tensorflow --- you can use any Python libraries you like to do this.

Hope that helps!